# How to display ERB code as it is (text) in RAILS 3.2 view (index/show)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http

We need to display ERB code in `index/show` views in a Rails 3.2 app. The problem we have is that the ERB code is executed instead of just being rendered as text.

We tried `URI.escape` and `CGI.escape`. Those 2 escapes alter the ERB code by adding symbols such as %A and %20. What's the right way to display ERB code as it is (text) in index/show views?

Comment: Do you read `ERB code` from file or the code is written in `index/show` views?

Comment: Yes, read ERB code from file and display it as it is in index/show view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<%%= %>` rather than `<%= %>`. As an example,

```
<%%= <%= %> <%= %> %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read code from a file in the controller (or somewhere else) and pass the code by variable to view, it should not be executed

```
# controller
def index
  @code = File.read("/tmp/a.erb")
end

# index.html.erb
<pre> <%= @code %> </pre>
```